# Add vrect with text to plotly express with button

Tags: python, button, plotly, visualization, plotly-python

I have the following code for a vertical rectangle in plotly express:

```
fig.add_vrect(
    x0 = '2020-04',
    x1 = '2020-09',
    fillcolor="red",
    opacity=0.25
)
```

I would like to make a button where the user can toggle with rectangle on and off, and when it's on there's some text in the middle. I would like them to be off by default.

Comment: The button should hide and show the rectangle, right? the rectangle has a text in the middle by default?

Comment: do you want the button to control both the rectangle and the text or just the text?

Comment: I want it to control both, and the text isn't there by default it'll probably be an annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dictionaries to create your rectangle shape and rectangle annotation and then use these as arguments for a [button](https://plotly.com/python/custom-buttons/). A few details: we use the `"relayout"` method for buttons because toggling a shape and text annotation means we are only changing the layout, and `args` and `args2` tells the button how to behave when toggled on/off.

Edit: in order to keep another shape (like a `vline`) on the figure, you can add the `vline` to both args and args2 of your button so the vline remains when the button is toggled

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(
    x=['2020-01-30', '2020-04-01', '2020-04-01','2020-09-01'],
    y=[3,2,3,2]
)

fig.add_vline(
    x='2020-02',
    line_dash='dash'
)

vline_shape = [dict(
    type='line',
    x0='2020-02',
    x1='2020-02',
    xref='x',
    y0=0,
    y1=1,
    yref='y domain',
    line= {'dash': 'dash'}
)]

rectangle_shape = [dict(
    type='rect',
    x0='2020-04',
    x1='2020-09',
    xref='x',
    y0=0,
    y1=1,
    yref='y domain',
    fillcolor='red',
    opacity=0.25
)]

rectangle_annotation = [dict(
    showarrow=False,
    x='2020-06-15',
    y=2.5,
    text="Selected Time Period"
)]

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type="buttons",
            buttons=[
                dict(label="Toggle Rectangle",
                     method="relayout",
                     args=[{
                        "shapes": rectangle_shape + vline_shape, 
                        "annotations": rectangle_annotation}],
                     args2=[{
                        "shapes": vline_shape, 
                        "annotations": []}]),
                # dict(label="Untoggle Rectangle",
                #      method="relayout",
                #      args=["shapes", []]),
            ],
        )
    ]
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I have a vline in the graph, and when I click the button, the rectangle appears but the vline disappears.

Comment: which other visuals do you mean?

Comment: A vline (vertical line in plotly express)

Comment: https://imgur.com/NuNUaKC

Comment: @imad97 you can add the vline to `args` and `args2` of your button so the vline remains – let me know if this looks good

Comment: Right now I have it under fig.add_vline. Would I need to add it as a shape?

Comment: `fig.add_vline` is a convenience function that adds a shape like the `vline_shape` that i constructed using a dictionary – you can use add_vline to add the vline to the figure initially (before you click the button), but in order to add a vline to the args, i need to pass some sort of object containing information about the vline to args and args of the button.